# SWT - Changing the printer's paper size programmatically

Tags: java, printing, swt

I've a application that does some batch printing with the *SWT API*. For that printing, I've to set programmatically all attributes of the printing configuration. Currently I'm able to set all attributes avaliable at `PrinterData` class.

The problem is that this class doesn't support setting page size and in various cases I'll have to set it to ISO A5 or A3 format, for example.

My question is: Has anybody found himself in this situation? How to solve it? Is it possible to edit `PrinterData.otherData` to define this property programmatically or only through a PrinterDialog?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Here is what I found out:

1. Setting the paper size with `PrinterData` is currently not possible. [Here](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=73290) is a bug report.
2. There is something called   [swt-printdialog-extension](http://code.google.com/p/swt-printdialog-extension/) which supposedly lets you set the size with windows 32bit.

Answer (score 0):

there is a walk around, after you use `PrintDialog.open()` you can take the PrinterData it returns and in it `PrinterData.otherData`there is the page size. I use this walkaround to let PaperClips print preview show me a print preview by the page size I selected